# A system of DEs with variable coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can i solve the following system of DE analytically(Is it possible)? i have been trying for a while but doesn't seem to get it. 
$$x''(t)= -z(t)x'(t)-x(t)+y(t),$$ $$y'(t)=-z(t)y(t)+x^2(t),$$ $$z'(t)=-2z^2(t)-x(t)$$

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I would say having a nontrivial analytical solution is highly unlikely.

Comment: Hello thanks for response, i was thinking maybe i can assume a solution based on the numerical  plot in Mathematica, for let's say z(t) or r(t) and then solve for others?

Answer (score 0):

Two "trivial" solutions are $x = y = 0$, $z = 1/(c + 2t)$, and $x=y=z=-1/2$.  Maple, after quite a long computation, "reduces" the general case to a very complicated nonlinear equation for $x'$ in terms of $x$.

EDIT: It comes, I think, from a complicated $5$'th order equation for $x(t)$:
$$\left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{4}}{{\rm d}{t}^{4}}}x \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{2}={\frac {25\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{4}+4\, \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{6}+2\,
 \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{5}- \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{6}-12\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}
^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{4}+6\, \left( {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( x
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}+15\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( x \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{4}+16\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}
}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{5}
-4\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{5}x
 \left( t \right) +12\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{4} \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}+52\,
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3}
 \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3}+33\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( x \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{4}-12\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{4}+36
\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{4}x \left( t \right) +12\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3} \left( {\frac {\rm d}
{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}+72\, \left( {\frac {
{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3} \left( x
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}+53\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( x \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{3}+18\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}
}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{4}+17\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( x \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{4}-36\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{4}x \left( t \right) +2\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{4}{\frac {{\rm d}^{4}}{{\rm d}
{t}^{4}}}x \left( t \right) -47\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3} \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2
}-6\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) 
 \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{4}+36\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{
3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3}{\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right) +27\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}
{t}^{3}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}+96\, \left( {\frac {
{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}+8\, \left( {
\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}
 \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}+85\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{
3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}
{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3}-20\, \left( {\frac {
{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3}x \left( 
t \right) -12\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{3}{\frac {{\rm d}^{4}}{{\rm d}{t}^{4}}}x \left( t
 \right) +4\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2}-11\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}
}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) 
^{2}-2\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t
 \right)  \right)  \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3}-2\, \left( 
x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3}{\frac {{\rm d}^{4}}{{\rm d}{t}^{4}}}x
 \left( t \right) +5\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3}-4\,
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{4}
 \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3}-20\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3} \left( x \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{4}-32\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{2} \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{5}-16\, \left( {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( x \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{6}-4\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t
 \right)  \right)  \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{5}-60\,
 \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) 
^{2} \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3}-20\, \left( {\frac {
{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( x \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{4}-60\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}
}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}x \left( t \right) -84\, \left( {\frac 
{{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( 
{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( x \left( 
t \right)  \right) ^{2}-42\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3
}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}
^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( x \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{2}+18\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}
}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3}-46\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2
}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( x \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{3}-94\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}
}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3}x \left( t \right) -128\, \left( {
\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) 
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}
 \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}+2\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{3
}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( x \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{3}+24\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3} \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x
 \left( t \right)  \right) x \left( t \right) +60\, \left( {\frac {
{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}x \left( t
 \right) +18\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t
 \right)  \right)  \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}+36\,
 \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) 
^{3}x \left( t \right) +37\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2
}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2
}-9\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) 
 \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3}+4\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3}x \left( t \right) {\frac {
{\rm d}^{4}}{{\rm d}{t}^{4}}}x \left( t \right) +8\, \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( x \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2}{\frac {{\rm d}^{4}}{{\rm d}{t}^{4}}}x \left( t
 \right) +8\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3}{\frac {{\rm d}^{4}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{4}}}x \left( t \right) +30\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {\frac {
{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) x \left( t
 \right) +30\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t
 \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t
 \right) +14\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t
 \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}-20\, \left( {\frac {
{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}x \left( 
t \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{4}}{{\rm d}{t}^{4}}}x \left( t \right) -18
\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) 
^{2}{\frac {{\rm d}^{4}}{{\rm d}{t}^{4}}}x \left( t \right) -11\,
 \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}{\frac {{\rm d}^{4}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{4}}}x \left( t \right) -9\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t
}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}x \left( t \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{
4}}{{\rm d}{t}^{4}}}x \left( t \right) +14\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2
}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}x \left( t \right) +28\,
 \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) 
^{3} \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}+88\, \left( {\frac {
{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( x
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3}+64\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( x \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{4}-36\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2
}-24\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{2} \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{3}-16\, \left( {\frac {
{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{4}x \left( t
 \right) -46\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t
 \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{3} \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}+36\, \left( {
\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) 
 \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) 
^{2}x \left( t \right) +24\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3
}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}
^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}
}x \left( t \right)  \right) x \left( t \right) +16\, \left( {\frac {
{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {
\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) 
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( x
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}+16\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}x \left( t \right) {\frac {
{\rm d}^{4}}{{\rm d}{t}^{4}}}x \left( t \right) +14\, \left( {\frac {
{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( x \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2}{\frac {{\rm d}^{4}}{{\rm d}{t}^{4}}}x \left( t
 \right) +43\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t
 \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t
 \right)  \right) x \left( t \right) -18\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}
{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{
2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}
{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{4}}{{\rm d}{t}
^{4}}}x \left( t \right) -10\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^
{3}}}x \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x
 \left( t \right)  \right) x \left( t \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{4}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{4}}}x \left( t \right) }{ \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}
x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. :)

Comment: Do you mean that maple can reduce the problem to a 1st order nonlinear ODE? This is surprising. I'd say it's 3rd order at least.

Comment: No, it's higher order (don't remember the order).  If $s = x(t)$ and $p = x'(t)$, it's a differential equation for $p$ as a function of $s$.